# Converting code from the Tornado python web framework to work independently

Tags: python, tornado

I need to use a library which depends on the Tornado Python Web Framework, but I cannot have it dependent on Tornado.

Does anyone have any advice when converting code over from this framework?

Has anything similar been attempted before (and the result published)?

Comment: Mind you tell what specific library/module you are converting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to create web-server-independent Python web apps is to code it to [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/), optionally using a [web framework](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). This way it can be used with any WSGI container.